How do you prove associativity for this operation?
Let $S$ be a set with a binary operation $/:S\times S \rightarrow S$ where $(a,b) \mapsto a/b$ such that:

There exists an element $1 \in S$, such that $a/b = 1$ if and only if $a=b$.

For any elements $a,b,c \in S$, $(a/c)/(b/c) = a/b$


Show that $S$ is a group under the product defined by $ab = a/(1/b)$
So far, I’ve proved the expected properties of the set, namely:
• $1/(a/b) = b/a$
• $a/1 = a$
• $1/a = 1/b \iff a=b$
• $a(1/b) = a/b$
For the group axioms, I have the identity (which is $1$) and the inverses ($a^{-1} = 1/a$). However, I’m having trouble showing associativity. I tried using the definition of the product but I don’t see how I can manipulate the expression to get an equality. I also tried computing $a(bc)/(ab)c$ to get the identity but failed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

If you are given that it is a binary operation, then you can easily show that right multiplication is a function, and thus that it is associative.

I don't follow you @Malady. By definition, that product is a binary operation, so right multiplication (by some fixed $b\in S$) is a function, But this does not imply that the product is associative.

Juan, how did you prove that $a/1=a$?

@Malady I used the fact that $a/1 = 1/(1/a)$ to show that $a/1 = (a/1)/1$. By the second property of $/$, this means that $(a/1)/((a/1)/1) = 1$. After some manipulation of that statement, you get $a/(a/1)=1$. Applying the second property of $/$ you get that $a$ must be equal to $a/1$

@Karl Yes, but since I couldn’t prove the group axioms directly I tried to get some properties that would allow me to do that. For instance, to prove that 1 is the identity element I had to use the fact that $a/1 = a$. Same thing for the inverses.

Short answer
$$\frac{a/(1/b)}{1/c}=\frac{(a/(1/b))\color{blue}{/(1/(1/b))}}{(1/c)\color{blue}{/(1/(1/b))}}=\frac{(a\color{red}{/(1/b)})/(1\color{red}{/(1/b)})}{(1/c)/(\color{red}{1/(1/b)})}=\frac{a}{(1/c)/b}=\frac{a}{1/(b/(1/c))}$$
which is the same as $(ab)c=a(bc)$
and we are done.
Long answer
You already did it (and it is easy), but I will go through the proofs of existence of identity and inverse and write down a complete solution.
So, to start, all of the three conditions of a group need us to show that something is equal to some other thing. Given the two facts at hand, our strategy to show that $a=b$ is to show that $a/b=1$. What we can also do is to find a $c$ such that $a/c=b/c$.
Note: For convenience, I will also use the fraction notation $\frac ab$ for $a/b$ at times.
Identity
Identity is the one that seems easiest. So, we want that $a\cdot1=a$ and $1\cdot a=a$, or equivalently $a/(1/1)=a$ and $1/(1/a)=a$.
Let us start with $a/(1/1)=a$. Since $1/1=1$, all we want is $a/1=a$. Here is the trick:
$$\frac{a/1}{1}=\frac{a/1}{1/1}=\frac{a}{1}$$
(which tells us that $\frac{a/1}{a}=\frac{(a/1)/1}{a/1}=1$.) We got rid of the $/1$ in the numerator by introducing $/1$ in the denominator and then using the cancellation property.
We can also write the above argument in one line:
$$\frac{a/1}{a}=\frac{(a/1)/(1/1)}{a/(1/1)}=\frac{a/1}{a/1}=1$$
If you don't see what is happening, what we have done is really
$$\frac{a/1}{a}=\frac{(a/1)\color{blue}{/(1/1)}}{a\color{blue}{/(1/1)}}=\frac{(a\color{red}{/1})/(1\color{red}{/1})}{a/(\color{red}{1/1})}=\frac{a/1}{a/1}$$
Idea: Take a fraction, introduce a common denominator on both numerator and the denominator, and then simplify the two new numerator and denominator separately.
This is exactly what will enable us to show associativity later (maybe try it yourself now, again). Before that, some easy things. Let us prove the other bit, which is rather trivial once we have done the first part:
$$\frac{1}{1/a}=\frac{a/a}{1/a}=\frac{a}{1}=a$$
Inverse
We expect that the inverse of $a$ is $1/a$ and in fact, that follows immediately, from the work in Identity.
$$a\cdot\frac1a=\frac{a}{1/(1/a)}=\frac{a}{a}=1$$
$$\frac1a\cdot a=\frac{1/a}{1/a}=1$$
Associativity
Let us write down $a(bc)=(ab)c$ in a more explicit form:
$$\frac{a}{1/(b/(1/c)))}=\frac{a/(1/b)}{1/c}$$
The denominator of the LHS can be easily simplified:
$$\frac{1}{b/(1/c)}=\frac{(1/c)/(1/c)}{b/(1/c)}=\frac{1/c}{b}$$
reducing our problem to showing that
$$\frac{a}{(1/c)/b}=\frac{a/(1/b)}{1/c}$$
Back to the trick and note that
$$\frac{a/(1/b)}{1/c}=\frac{(a/(1/b))\color{blue}{/(1/(1/b))}}{(1/c)\color{blue}{/(1/(1/b))}}=\frac{(a\color{red}{/(1/b)})/(1\color{red}{/(1/b)})}{(1/c)/(\color{red}{1/(1/b)})}=\frac{a}{(1/c)/b}$$
and we are done.
Hope this helps. :)
